# Namenode has not been started in slave node when i create master slave configuration in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

```
  When i setup master slave configuration in HADOOP2.2.0 and perform start-yarn.sh
```

command than after resource manager has been started successfully in master node but node-manager has not been started successfully in slave node. I already double check all the configuration and setting which is needed for master-slave configuration.

Comment: Check your logs in all of the nodes. You most likely have some connection errors which need to be fixed.